# mysql collection of visitor days?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table - table1.  It has ID (autoinc), dt (datetime), name (varchar) columns.  When a visitor visits they can enter their name in the database.  On some days their are no visitors.

From this, i'm trying to find if their is some way to make a list in php of all days for which their was at least 1 visitor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this paradox. If there was no visitor, there is no entry, so there is nothing to retrieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select distinct date(dt) from table1
```

So then, in php you would do something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("select distinct date(dt) from table1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row[0] . "\n";
}
```

This would print each date on a different line.

Should give you a list of the unique dates that data  was written to the table.

**Updated to use date() instead of day()**
**Updated to fix the missing parenthesis **

Comment: `DAY()` does not return a date, it returns a day number (e.g: 11).

Comment: Mysql is super short and sweet. win!

Comment: its not letting me edit, but basically ther is a end ) missing in the while loop...

Answer (score 0):

To extract only those dates.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%m-%d') AS the_date,
       COUNT(*) AS visitors

  FROM table

 GROUP BY the_date

HAVING visitors > 0;
```